# Access a Controller return value in a View

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

In my controller I have this method

```
<?php

function test($value){              

    $products = $this->Model->getProducts($id);

    for($i=0; $i < count($products); $i++){ 
        foreach ($products[$i] as $key => $value) {
            return $value;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

How can I access this from inside a View?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you generate a variable in the controller, and want to access it in the view, you can use

```
$this->set('value', $value);
```

This will allow you to use $value in the relevant view as well.

If you actually want to access a function from the view, you don't want want to put that function in the controller, but in a helper.  (As a rule of thumb, you put functions you want to be accessible to your views in helpers, and functions you want to accessible to your controller in components.)  Might be worth reading up more on helpers in the Cake Cookbook etc if you don't know where to start!

EDIT: For getting all the relevant values of your loop, you could try something like:

```
$products = $this->Model->getProducts($id);
$results = array();

for($i=0; $i < count($products); $i++){ 
    foreach ($products[$i] as $key => $value) {
        $results[] = $value;
    }
 }

$this->set(compact('results'));
```

Comment: problem is that I am in foreach loop and it sets the value to the last item in the loop

Comment: if I do  pr($value) it works fine but if I use set..it only returns the last item in array

Comment: Aha, I see - that seems like sort of a separate issue.  When the code reaches a "return" statement it will quit the loop immediately.  You probably want to assign all the values to an array and then return that array.  Hang on...

Comment: I made an edit to my answer that will maybe help you get a full array of values, instead of just one?

Comment: I think the question should be edited to be in sync with your answer :)